# explain why one can write $\hat{f}(\xi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx$ when $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ where the measure is taken to be the Lebesgue measure. The Fourier transform of $f$ is the function $\hat{f}$ defined as 
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx \qquad ,\xi\in \mathbb{R}$$

(Plancherel Forumla) If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\|f\|_2=\|\hat{f}\|_2$

(*) Assuming this result, we can extend the Fourier transform to an isometric operator $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be arbitrary. Using the idea (*), explain why one can write $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx$$

---

In this question,

1. Is the equality $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx$$ correct?
2. If the above equality is correct, do we need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx<\infty$  i.e.  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$?

How can we solve the question? Thanks!

---

### Update

Let $f_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}f$. Is it enough to show the following steps?

1. $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$
2. $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and $L^1$ as $n\to\infty$
3. $\hat{f_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n} e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx$

If the answer yes, my attempt is the following:

1. Note that $|f_n|<|f|$ implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|^2<\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^2<\infty$ . So $f_n\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. On the other hand we have 
   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n|=\int_{[-n,n]}|f_n|\leq \sqrt{\int_{[-n,n]}|f_n|^2}\sqrt{\int_{[-n,n]}\textbf{1}^2}=\sqrt{\int_{[-n,n]}|f_n|^2}.\mathcal{L}([-n,n])<\infty$$ So $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ as well.
2. $|f_n-f|^2= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & \text{on $[-n,n]$}\\
       |f|^2 &  \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
   $

So $$\|f_n-f\|_2^2=\int |f_n-f|^2=\int_{[-n,n]}|f_n-f|^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-n,n]}|f_n-f|^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-n,n]}|f|^2$$
So $\|f_n-f\|_2\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Similarly $\|f_n-f\|_1 \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

3. By definition, it is obvious.

Comment: $L^2$ is made to avoid considerations about the pointwise convergence. if $f \in L^2$, with $\hat{f_n}(\xi) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-n}^n e^{-i\xi x}f(x) dx$ you have (and this is the definition of $\hat{f}$) : $\lim_{n \to \infty } \|\hat{f_n}-\hat{f}\|_{L^2} = 0$

Comment: No, the equality in (1) is not correct; the integral on the right need not exist. "Explain why we can write..." If you mean that formula holds almost everywhere, that's true but it's incredibly hard to prove - that's not what the exercise wants, at least if the person who wrote the exercise knows what's what. The convergence is in the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that if $f_n:=\chi_{[-n,n]}f$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$ pointwise then $\hat{f_n}$ converges to $\hat{f}$ pointwise?Thanks

Comment: Yes, $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ and hence $\hat f_n\to\hat f$ in $L^2$. (Not sure what your point is; this does not show that the equality in (1) is correct; the integral on the right does not exist, hence cannot equal $\hat f(\xi)$.)

Comment: the Parseval equality means that if $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2 \cap L^1$, then $\hat{f_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence $ \in L^2$, i.e. that it converges to some $g \in L^2$, and by definition this is $\hat{f}$ :$$\hat{f} \ \ \overset{def}= \ \underset{\text{in the sense  of } L^2}{\lim_{n \to \infty}  \hat{f_n}}$$

Comment: For your update, no it is not enough. $L^2$ convergence does not imply pointwise convergence. @DavidC.Ullrich, the comment you wrote in my (now deleted) answer is spot on and might answer the doubt of the OP. You may consider writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is typically how one would go about equating the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ extension of the Fourier transform to the classical integral transform.

**Theorem:** Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose that the following exists for almost every $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
           g(\xi) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n} f(t)e^{-it\xi}dt.
$$
Then $g = \hat{f}$ a.e., where $\hat{f}$ is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ limit of the integral on the right.

**Proof:** Suppose $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and define
$$
             g_n(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)e^{-i\xi t}dt.
$$
The integral on the right is absolutely convergent for every $n$ because  $\chi_{[-n,n]}f \in L^1$. By Parseval's identity,
$$
          \lim_n \|g_n-\hat{f}\|_{L^2}=0.
$$
By standard results of $L^2$, there is a subsequence $\{ g_{n_k} \}$ that converges pointwise a.e.. to $\hat{f}$. By assumption, $\{ g_n(\xi) \}$ converges pointwise a.e. to $g$. Hence, $g=\hat{f}$ must hold a.e.. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Why are we using Parseval's identity meant for Fourier series?

Comment: @s.t.a.l.k.e.r_2133 Sometimes people mix up Parseval and Plancherel, since they are essentially the same idea.

Comment: @Ian . Ok but it can confuse slow learners like me.

Comment: @s.t.a.l.k.e.r_2133 I didn't say it was a good thing that people mix up Parseval and Plancherel, just saying that that's what happened.

Comment: @s.t.a.l.k.e.r_2133 : For the special case of the Fourier tranform, the $L^2$ identity is often referred to as Parsevals' Theorem in Science and Engineering, which is where I first learned it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Answer (score -1):

$f \in L^2$

$\hat{f}= \lim\limits_{u,v\mapsto \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^v fe^{-isx}dx$

multiply $f$ by a bump function $g_n$ with compact support in $[-u,v]$

such that $ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}g_nf=f$ on $[-u,v]$

let $h_n=g_nf$$\quad$ $h_n \in L^1 \bigcap L^2$ and $\hat{h}_n \in L^2 $(Plancherel theorem)

Also $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\hat{h}_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^v fe^{-isx}dx$

The good part is that the sequence {$h_n$} is uniformly integrable over $[-u,v]$: this follows from property of bump function.
These imply $\hat{f} \in L^2$

Fourier Inversion theorem:$$
     \lim_{u,v\rightarrow\infty}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^{v}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-h_n\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \;\;\; 
$$

Plancherel theorem:$$
     \lim_{u,v\rightarrow\infty}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-u}^{v}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-h_n\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \;\;\; 
$$

for sufficiently large $n,u,v$:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}_n(s)e^{isx}ds)^2dx \le \delta$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}({h}_n-f)^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-f)^2dx \le \epsilon$$

writing $(a-b)^2=(a-c+c-b)^2=(a-c)^2+(c-b)^2+2(a-c)(c-b)$ and by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f-\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds)^2 dx\le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}((\int_{-u}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds)^2+(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\hat{h}_n(s)e^{isx}ds-f)^2)dx +(2\delta \epsilon)^{1/2}\le\delta+\epsilon+2(\delta \epsilon)^{1/2}$$